# Inconsistent Filtering Results After Date Conversion with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I imported a CSV file using the pandas library's read_csv function and then used the to_datetime function to convert two columns in the dataset. The original format of these columns looks like this:

- **COL_1**: 2023-09-30 05:19:20.078
- **COL_2**: 2023-09-30

However, when I attempt to filter the DataFrame, I observe different results for these columns:

- For **COL_1**, when I use the condition **df['COL_1'] == '2023-09-30'**, it returns **False**.
- For **COL_2**, when I use the condition **df['COL_2'] == '2023-09-30'**, it returns **True**.

This difference in results might raise questions about how the to_datetime function works. Any ideas?

Comment: `df['COL_1']` has a time on it, so when you compare it to a value which doesn't have a time, it doesn't match.